# Scroll an NSTextView to bottom after adding text

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift4, nstextview

I want to add text to an NSTextView and scroll it to the bottom like it is done in the console of Xcode. What is the best way to do that in swift 4? I have looked at other answers but they are not in swift or do not work perfectly in when converted to swift.

This is being written for an OS X app and not an iOS app and that is why I am asking about an NSTextView.

To add text, I am simply I am using this code `self.logTextView.string += "\nnew text"` This allows the text to also be put on a new line. If there is a better way to do this, would love to hear it.

Here is what I have tried already: 
[Scrolling NSTextView to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546808/scrolling-nstextview-to-bottom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSTextView has an exact action: `scrollToEndOfDocument(_ sender: Any?)`.

So, I suppose the following code is enough.

```
self.logTextView.string += "\nnew text"
self.logTextView.scrollToEndOfDocument(nil)
```

Comment: I had tried this and it worked perfectly when I could see the textView. But my textView is inside a scrollview and when a log is added to the textview and the textview is not visible within the scrollview, it does not work. Do you know what might be causing this? Basically, the log textview is at the bottom and the buttons to add to the log are at the top. When I scroll to the bottom, the textview is not scrolled to the bottom with the code "scrollToEndOfDocument"

Comment: Isn't your NSTextView the documentView of the wrapper NSScrollView? Or you have nested NSScrollViews? Basically, NSTextViews should always be used as the documentView of an NSScrollView.

Comment: I am an iOS developer so I am not familiar with the nuances of OS X development. I basically just dragged a scrollview and then within it, I put a NSTextView.

Comment: If you use Storyboard or xib, the NSTextView, you dragged into an NSScrollView, may also have its own NSScrollView wrapping it. Hence, to show the bottom line of the textView, you need to scroll both scrollViews.