# NSTextView Scroll to bottom only if currently scrolled to the bottom?

Tags: swift, macos, nstextview

I'm trying to figure out how I can scroll to bottom and only scroll to bottom if the scroll position is at the bottom, like XCODE.

I can't figure out how I can get the current scroll position of an NSTextView.

It's simple to just scroll to the bottom using:

```
self.tbLog.scrollToEndOfDocument(nil)
```

But this happens every time and if you are scrolled up to the top of a log file and a new line is added, it drops back to the bottom.  I only want to drop to the bottom if the scroll position is at the bottom.

**SOLUTION**:

```
// Add your text to the NSTextView here... then...
print("Position: \(NSMaxY(self.tbLog.visibleRect) - NSMaxY(self.tbLog.bounds))")
if (NSMaxY(self.tbLog.visibleRect) - NSMaxY(self.tbLog.bounds) == 0.0) { 
     print("we're at the bottom, keep at the bottom.")
     self.tbLog.scrollToEndOfDocument(nil)
} else {
     print("we're scrolled up somewhere... do nothing.")
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546808/scrolling-nstextview-to-bottom You can check whether you are at the bottom before you add sth witht he above and then go to bottom after adding.

Comment: Thanks -- added solution above for others.

Comment: Its usual to add the solution as your own answer below separate from the question, but I dont personally care whether you do it or not. Good that you found a fix!

Comment: Agree - posted solution since this in SWIFT vs Objc hopefully can help others. Thanks again!